# Where do I get started on building an HTML5 form in SharePoint?

Tags: development, custom-form, database, sql, html5

Working on a project to build an HTML5 form within SharePoint that will read and write to a SQL database. Can't find much online about how to get this implemented. I am very well versed in HTML and SharePoint. Just need to know where to start.

Comment: Could you provide more info? I think you can start with an application page but no sure...

Comment: Just looking for the basics: where to build it, what software I would need, to it works to get it connected to a database. Any articles you could point me to would be great.

Comment: In the answer below I left you a link to get started. SharePoint development has many variants. That book is very good. You'll get some key concepts. Since there are many possible ways to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start with this book, **"Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010"**.

The first 4 chapters can be read online at MSDN this link: [Book landing page: Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff742318(v=office.14).aspx)

There are versions of this book for 2007 and 2013 too.